# Can I use a structure without slugs?

Tags: structure, slug

I'm making a portfolio website, where the url's look like "projects/project-name".
There is also an overview page with all the projects that is under "projects" on itself.

I'm using a Structure for this, but I go to the 404 page when I'm just trying to go to "projects" without the slugs.

Is there a way of using a structure without a slug?

Comment: I am also interested in this question. I created a navigation with a structure. Now I want to get rid of this slugs. Because it will appear in the sitemap. And this pages are error pages without a template. Is there a way to create structure entries without a slug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a listing template for the base `/projects` URL, and make that template render for that URL.

The easiest way is to just add a template called `/templates/projects/index.html`, in which case Craft will automatically render that template whenever a user hits `example.com/projects`.

Another way is to create a [dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes), and point it to whatever template you want rendered for the `/projects` URL.

Obviously, inside your listing template you'll need to pull the Structure entries manually, i.e. by doing something like this:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projects') %}
    <article>
        <h2><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
        ...
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that if you don't pass an `.order()` parameter to your `craft.entries` query, Craft will use the default order, which is the "manual" `structure` order for Structure sections.

Also note that if your Structure is multi-level, you'll probably want to use the [`{% nav %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/nav) tag over the basic `{% for %}` loop:

```
{% nav entry in craft.entries.section('projects') %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```