# How can I set a landing page for a structure with no slug?

Tags: url, structure

In Craft2, I have structures that each have a landing page/homepage for that structure.

If the structure's URI format is "liver/{slug}", how do I make the 'landing page' entry have a URI of only "liver/", with no slug?

This is important since I want users visiting the liver/about-us page to be able to remove 'about-us'...and land on the liver homepage (not get a 404).

I don't understand routing very well-- from what I have gleaned I cannot see how to make routing associate a given URI with a given entry-- I only understand how to associate it with a template.

This is similar to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/can-i-use-a-structure-without-slugs), except that I want these landing pages to have dashboard entries and use the same template as all the other pages...not be an index-type page.

Note: I have seen answers regarding adding a site homepage to a structure, but this is not a site homepage- these landing pages do not live at the site domain root...they live at the root of each structure's URI.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create change the `uri` pattern for your structured section to something like `{ parent.uri }/{ slug }` and create an additional entry type `landing-page`. Your landing page will have the slug `liver` and all entries below that will have the URI `liver/{slug}`

You can load different templates based on the entry type and if the type is your landing page, you'll display all children

Another Approach is to use a `template` path directly and insert the template `liver.twig` in your templates folder

Comment: Interesting idea...thank you! My hesitation is that the 'liver/' subsite encompasses a number of structures...but only one of them houses the liver homepage. So I have primary and secondary navigations...and a utility nav that includes the homepage. I will think about this and try it before marking it correct...as well as see if there are alternative suggestions.

Comment: now I marked it as correct. It worked...thank you!